# how to limit option width with very long text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I tried but am unable to control the option width when text is very long. How to limit the width of the option or at least be same as the select.
Using bootstrap and asp.net mvc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAQta.png

css as below

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

select{
    width:200px
}
```

code is just normal mvc

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserInfoId, "Choose Masseur", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserInfoId", null, "No preference", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserInfoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

the html generate as below

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="UserInfoId">Choose Masseur</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="UserInfoId" name="UserInfoId"><option value="">No preference</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Lisa lee : Although she looks young, but Lisa is very experienced in curing massage, slim down massage and ease insomnia problem. She is working from 9pm to 9am (night shift), better place an online booking or call 65547388 for a booking, she is always fully booked every day.</option>
<option value="3">Wendy lee : Wendy is from Vietnam,experienced, very kind and nice to talk, she can speak in Chinese and English. Off on Saturday.    </option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-    valmsg-for="UserInfoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code that you are using so that we are able to help you

Comment: code shared, somehow option width just unable to set

Comment: please, you should use [twitter-bootstrap], not the program that boots the computer

Comment: not sure what u mean, this is using twitter bootstrap, actually it does not matter, without bootstrap still the same, the option is very wide http://i.imgur.com/E5nrFVB.png

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width by directing targeting the select tag.

```
select{
    width:200px
}
```

EDIT: Apparently you can only set at width for the `<option>` tag in some browers. Every browser will react differently. In Firefox, for example, you can see the option width being set properly.

[image: option tag width on chrome] 
You might want to try truncating the text before it is added as an option tag. Either with javascript, or on the server side. Hope this helps!

Comment: Still the same, no changes

Comment: There is a good chance that since you are using bootstrap there are other styles taking precedence. Do you know how to use inspect element?

Comment: Yes i do, using chrome to inspect it, will remove bootstrap and try simple css to see it it work first. Thank you.

Comment: I tried using http://codepen.io/pen/ and it is the same, option very wide http://i.imgur.com/E5nrFVB.png

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. So I learned something very interesting about this. Apparently it can be done when viewing in firefox, but not when viewing in chrome. The best idea is to truncate text using server side programming, or perhaps a little javascript. In other words, shorten the text before you put it into an option tag.

Answer (score 0):

**might be helpful to solve your problems**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="UserInfoId">Choose Masseur</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="UserInfoId" name="UserInfoId" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large"  >
<option value="">No preference</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Lisa lee : Although she looks young, but Lisa is very experienced in curing massage, slim down massage and ease insomnia problem. She is working from 9pm to 9am (night shift), better place an online booking or call 65547388 for a booking, she is always fully booked every day.</option>
<option value="3">Wendy lee : Wendy is from Vietnam,experienced, very kind and nice to talk, she can speak in Chinese and English. Off on Saturday.    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Need it to be dropdown hence multiple cannot be used